# Does transport building reduce traffic on roads?

Tags: simcity-buildit

If I build transport service building (like an heliport), will it reduce the traffic on my roads or does transport building only raise the number of Sims in my city?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’m pretty sure the transport specialisation doesn’t reduce traffic. It’s a specialisation, which only increases population so I don’t think it would have any other special benefits.